# old images show after replacing with new ones in ios app

Tags: iphone, image, compiler-errors, iso

I am dealing with this really really annoying bug in X-Code where it seems to save images to some type of memory that seems impossible to clear.
I have replaced a bunch of images in which I am creating a clock animation however when I try to play the animation it showes all the old images, I have tried cleaning the app and still they continue to show even though I have deleted the images.. So then I tried changing the name of the images along with the code where they were getting called and now I'm getting a bunch more errors, So I'm just woundering if anyone knows how to get around this problem of xcode caching images.

Comment: I have this problem and clean did not fix it.  In fact I removed the resource from the project and it still finds the old image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to clean the build or delete it from the device/simulator. That usually takes care of it if you're sure the files are named correctly. Also make sure that you're using the correct case in your filenames, that messed me up a few times. :)

Comment: cleaning the solution helped me out with this problem! :)

Comment: To clarify, you can search in Finder for <NameOfMyApp>.app to quickly find the file in the simulator folder and delete it.  Make sure in the Finder search to turn on the option to search in System folders.

Answer (score 1):

- In the XCode explorer, right click on the image, use "Show in finder" and make sure they refer to the images you want.
- Try using the Clean option from the Product menu in XCode.